# How do I check if a JavaScript parameter is a number?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some trouble-shooting and want to add a check that a parameter to a function is a number. How do I do this?

Something like this...

```
function fn(id) {
    return // true iff id is a number else false
}
```

Even better is if I can check that the parameter is a number AND a valid integer.

Comment: Per my specific case I was able to use `if(+id == id)` which works with numbers, not alphabet (alpha chars return `NaN`).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
function fn(id) {
    return typeof(id) === 'number';
}
```

To also check if it’s an integer:

```
function fn(id) {
    return typeof(id) === 'number' &&
            isFinite(id) &&
            Math.round(id) === id;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

i'd say

```
 n === parseInt(n)
```

is enough. note three '===' - it checks both type and value

Comment: you are lucky that `NaN===NaN is false`

Answer (score 2):

Check if the type is number, and whether it is an int using `parseInt`:

`if (typeof id == "number" && id == parseInt(id))`

Answer (score 2):

=== means strictly equals to and == checks if values are equal.
that means "2"==2 is true but "2"===2 is false.

using regular expression

```
var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
if(intRegex.test(num1)) { 
//num1 is a valid integer
}
```

**example of**
[== vs. ===](http://jsfiddle.net/LcgPh/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function fn(id){ 
  if((parseFloat(id) == parseInt(id)) && !isNaN(id)){
      return true;
  } else { 
      return false;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function fn(id) {
    var x = /^(\+|-)?\d+$/;
    if (x.test(id)) {
        //integer
        return true;
    }
    else {
        //not an integer
        return false;
    }
}
```

Test fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xLYW7/