# How to return only numeric values?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, numbers, average

I am trying to return the average. How can I get only the numbers and leave out false, "str"?

```
function average2 () {
    console.log (`arguments passed: ${arguments.length}`)
    console.log("All arguments:");
    let sum = 0;
    let numOnly = arguments.match(/\d+/)[0]
    for (let i= 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        sum += arguments[i]
    }
    return (sum) / arguments.length
}
console.log (average2 (5, 6, false, "str", 100))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: An `if` + some way of testing for a number, e.g. [How do I check if a JavaScript parameter is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441787/how-do-i-check-if-a-javascript-parameter-is-a-number)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter numbers by using `typeof` operator, like this:

```js
function average (...params) {
    const nums = params.filter(n => typeof n == 'number');
    return nums.reduce((acc,n) => acc+n) / nums.length;
}
console.log (average (5, 6, false, "str", 7))
```

in this example I just calculated average of nums, if you want to calculate average based on arguments length, you can replace `return nums.reduce((acc,n) => acc+n) / nums.length;` with `return nums.reduce((acc,n) => acc+n) / params.length;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
function average() {
    const numericArgs = [...arguments].filter(x => typeof x === 'number');
    return numericArgs.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / numericArgs.length;
}
```

And you can use this:

```
function average(...args) {
    const numericArgs = args.filter(x => typeof x === 'number');
    return numericArgs.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / numericArgs.length;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add a type check before doing the addition:

```js
function average2 () {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i= 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      if(typeof arguments[i] === "number"){
        sum += arguments[i]
      }
    }
    return (sum) / arguments.length
}
console.log (average2 (5, 6, false, "str", 100))
```